# How to display quotient as a percentage

Tags: postgresql, percentage

I am using Postgresql to generate a simple quotient of two fields " a / b " = -3 / 300 = -.01 or -1.00%.  Instead it displays as zero.  I've tried many variations of to_char with no success.  How could I get "select -3/300 as quotient" to display the quotient in xxx.xxx% format?  Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate? Because last time I checked `(3 / 300) == 0`, Postgres does integer division for input integers. Hence, `(a / b::float) * 100.0` might be a better idea.

Comment: Please elaborate by giving a more detailed example and describe exactly what step you took and what didn't work as expected.

Comment: Sure, it's actually (-3 / 300) = 0.01 = 1.00%, and the ::float suggestion makes a difference!  Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

To display with the percentage sign, you can use the following format. Don't forget to first multiply by 100.0 so 1) is it indeed a percentage and 2) as noted by @dhke the computation is done with floats, not integers.

```
select to_char(100.0*-3/300,'999D99%') a;
    a
----------
   -1.00%
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, JGH, this did yield positive changes.  The "::float" suggestion above put me over the finish line but this technique for using no_char is one I will keep handy, it gives me more options.  Thank you.

Comment: Great answer, I would also suggest using '990D99%' for formatting, to get 0.23% instead of .23%